# Upload files up to 4 gig

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, iis-7.5

How can I upload files up to 4 giga bytes in iis7.5 and mvc3
Note: I already maxAllowedContentLength

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
       <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4194304" />
```

but I still can not upload file with size 3.71 giga file

Is there is something I forget to do?????

Comment: that will take a very very long time to upload. can the file not be zipped?

Comment: The time is not important in my case, and all the file is zipped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET (even the .NET 4 version) has a 2 GB limit!

Also when uploading such large files, you'd better think of using some (3rd party) tool that makes your uploading more stable. This makes your user a lot happier as well.

I have read that .NET 4.5 should support larger files. But still then i'd provide my users with a plugin like this: http://neatupload.codeplex.com